# yii2 datepicker disable dates using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, yii2

I rewrited my question:

I'm using [Kartick DatePicker](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker) to display a datepicker. On this datepicker, I want to disable dates using javascript. Here is what I have:

```
<?= DatePicker::widget([
    'name' => 'mydate',
          'language' => 'fr',
          'clientOptions' => [
              'autoclose' => true,
              'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy'
          ]
  ]);?>
```

With the JS:

```
 $(function(){
     $("#w0").datepicker("setDatesDisabled", ['25-08-2017']);
});
```

I tried to change the format of the date to `2017/08/25` or `08/25/2017` but in any case nothing is displayed into the logs.

I also tried to use `kvDatepicker()` instead of `datepicker()` but this gave me

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).kvDatepicker is not a function

Any clue on what is wrong here? Thank's.

Comment: you need to let us know which Datepicker plugin you are using

Comment: You are using variable `unavailable` before it's defined - move `$(function(){...})` after `function unavailable(date) {...}` and rename it to `unavailable()`. Actually whole second section needs rewrite - you are messing up variable & function names ...

Comment: I ended up using `disabledDates` which I didn't saw before. So I do not need to call my function anymore. Could you check my update please? @csminb I'm using the datepicker from JQuery available on GitHub, do you need more info?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your date is in the wrong format. It should be specified as:

```
$("#w0").datepicker("setDatesDisabled", ['08/25/2017']);
```

Of course make sure that `w0` is the correct ID for the `input` element... it might also be that your selector doesn't match the `input`.

I've verified on the [demo](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on&datesDisabled=on#sandbox) page that entering this in the browser's console correctly disables Aug 28:

```
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker("setDatesDisabled", ['08/28/2017']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Yii2 Specifically than this may help you

```
    echo '<label id = "for-trigger">Date</label>';
                echo DatePicker::widget([
                    'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_INPUT,
                    'id' => 'anyUniqueID',
                    'name' => 'date',
                    'value' => '2020-04-11',
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Selectdate ...'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'format' => 'yyyy-M-dd',
                        'daysOfWeekHighlighted' => '2,3',
                        'todayHighlight' => true,
                        'datesDisabled' => ['2020-04-06', '2020-04-21']
                    ],
                    'pluginEvents' => [
                        'changeDate' => "function(e) {  
                            //something you want to do may be 
                        }"
                    ]
                ]);
```